# No file preview while opening an image in 22.04

Tags: nautilus, firefox, gimp, 22.04, thumbnails

In 21.10, when I try open a file, I could see a thumbnail preview on the right. This was true with Firefox, GIMP and Inkscape.

Sadly, after upgrading to 22.04, all I got are file names and an image icon in Nautilus.

Is it possible to somehow see which file we are adding to Firefox, GIMP etc as a thumbnail preview as available in 21.10 and earlier? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Icon view in google chrome file chooser is gone on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406730/icon-view-in-google-chrome-file-chooser-is-gone-on-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: @vanadium: Your link is a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron you are right, this one came earlier. That is because I first saw the other question. I cannot remove my close vote  anymore, however.

Answer (score 8):

Ubuntu 22.04 and Firefox 104:

Type `about:config` in the address bar to be able to access the advanced settings page and confirm that you accept the risk.

Set `widget.use-xdg-desktop-portal.file-picker` to 0.

Comment: I would love to have the same solution for Brave (Chromium based browwser)

Answer (score 1):

## *Ubuntu 20.04.x*

Gimp 2.10.28

Open Gimp
Menu > Edit > Preferences > System Resources > Image Thumbnails
Select something else than "No thumbnails"

---

Nautilus (from Bash prompt), AKA "Files":

The three dash (horizontal version of `///`) clickable gadget just beside "_" (minimize window) in the upper right corner of the window has the settings.
In that menu you have `Preferences` > `Search and preview` (tab) > Thumbnails: move away from `Never` if set to that.

---

Firefox 99.0:

Enter `about:config` in the address field
Click `Accept the risk ...`
Then type `Thumbnail` in the search field that appears.
*(No related settings as it seems, hmm? Neither so in `Settings`)*

Comment: It is already set as " Normal ". thanks

Comment: i.e. 128x128 px

Comment: Nautilus says Thumbnails > On this computer only

Comment: I think you mistook 22.04 with 20.04

Comment: @user227495 nope, I don't have 22.04 installed, just 20.04. Reading "22.04; changes from 20.04 " articles has not mentioned this kind of detail(s).

Comment: No problem. Thanks.