# 22.04: Image Preview in File Selector menu

Tags: filemanager, previews

I updated ubuntu to 22.04 version and the preview of files when I open a file selector menu, for example to upload a image to twitter via browser, doesn't work anymore, how I can enable this feature? Thank you:

Now:
[image]

I would like something like this:
[image]

thank you :)

Comment: This problem was especially annoying for me when using Firefox. If that's your case too, this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405785/no-file-preview-while-opening-an-image-in-22-04

Answer (score 6):

Feature was removed in GTK4.

Emmanuele Bassi from the GNOME Team:

> The preview in GTK3 is provided by the application itself, not the toolkit.
> In GTK4, the preview widget API has been removed, as it cannot be used with native/sandboxed file choosers.

https://discourse.gnome.org/t/file-chooser-gtk-4-does-not-show-image-prveiew/10429

Comment: ok, I understand it, but this is not a solution

Answer (score 5):

Dolphin File Manager from KDE can preview files.

So I installed Dolphin Files Manager App on Gnome 42.5 and make Dolphin as default files manager. It's work!
[Set Dolphin as default file manager at Gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84929/how-to-set-up-dolphin-as-default-file-manager)

Now I can see file preview when I call file picker.